# Android upload file in chunks to PHP

Tags: php, android, upload, chunked

How can we upload big files in chunks to a PHP server so that if the connection dies, the upload can be resumed at any time.

Specifically, what libraries are needed in Android to do this?

The users are uploading big files from countries with slow/unstable internet connections. Thank you

EDIT

More info, I'm currently using HTTP POST to upload the whole file at once. As the following code shows:

```
private int uploadFiles(File file) {
        String zipName = file.getAbsolutePath() + ".zip";
        if(!zipFiles(file.listFiles(), zipName)){
            //return -1;
            publishResults(-1);
        }
        //publishProgress(-1, 100);
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
        DataInputStream inputStream = null;

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String serverUrl = prefs.getString("serverUrl", "ServerGoesHere"); // todo ensure that a valid string is always stored
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        int responseCode = -1;
        try {
            //notif title, undeterministic
            pNotif.setContentText("Zipping complete. Now Uploading...")
                  .setProgress(0, 0, true);
            mNotifyManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, pNotif.build()); // make undeterministic

            //update progress bar to indeterminate
            sendUpdate(0, 0, "Uploading file."); // sendupdate using intent extras

            File uploadFile = new File(zipName);
            long totalBytes = uploadFile.length();
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);

            URL url = new URL(serverUrl);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);

            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            outputStream
            .writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\""
                    + zipName + "\"" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            long bytesUploaded = 0;
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                bytesUploaded += bytesRead;
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                //int percentCompleted = (int) ((100 * bytesUploaded) / totalBytes);
                //publishProgress((int)bytesUploaded/1024, (int)totalBytes/1024);

                System.out.println("bytesRead> " + bytesRead);
            }

            //publishProgress(-2, 1); // switch to clean up
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
                    + lineEnd);
            try {
                responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            fileInputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            // Delete the zip file
            new File(zipName).delete();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            new File(zipName).delete();
            responseCode = -1;
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return responseCode;
    }
```

Is there a way to modify this to send it by chunks? Most of the research I've done has not been very clear, sorry

Comment: Can`t you send another request to the server telling it that the upload was done? Or prepare the file : temp_file into several and foreach file call the webserver (a historisation function) and flag a partial upload, you would know that 5 files out of 10 were successfully inserted

Comment: The Transport control protocol (TCP) is designed to ensure every packets arrival in the right order and without loss. You could just use HTTP PUT or POST methods to upload, since HTTP uses TCP.

Comment: I'm using HTTP POST to send the whole file @TmKVU.

Comment: @KA_lin so I would need to open a connection for each chunk?

Comment: @apSTRK If you want to upload in chunks, HTTP is not the protocol to use. HTTP is stateless and you would indeed need to open a connection for every chunk. I would use socket programming and maintain a TCP connection between your app and the server until the upload is done.

Comment: @apSTRK I made my comment into an answer which you can accept if socket programming works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing resumable uploads using an SFTP library. JSch http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/
I upload using SFTP and the library handles the resumable mode. Example code:

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
session = jsch.getSession(FTPS_USER,FTPS_HOST,FTPS_PORT);
session.setPassword(FTPS_PASS);
java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(config);
session.connect();
channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
channel.connect();
channelSftp = (ChannelSftp)channel;
channelSftp.cd(FTPS_PATH);

File uploadFile = new File(zipName); // File to upload
totalSize = uploadFile.length(); // size of file

// If part of the file has been uploaded, it saves the number of bytes. Else 0
try {
    totalTransfer = channelSftp.lstat(uploadFile.getName()).getSize();
} catch (Exception e) {
    totalTransfer = 0;
}

// Upload File with the resumable attribute
channelSftp.put(new FileInputStream(uploadFile), uploadFile.getName(), new SystemOutProgressMonitor(), ChannelSftp.RESUME);

channelSftp.exit();
session.disconnect();
```

With this library I fulfilled all the requirements: resumable uploads and upload progress.

Comment: I think you can use socket.io to maintain your connection while sending files and once finished you can send an event to mean that it completed! I made it in web with Node JS and i don't use PHP to do it. So i want to do the same in android i used this link https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-resumable-video-uploader-in-nodejs--net-25445

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to upload a file in chunks via HTTP, since it is a stateless protocol and you would need to make a new connection for every chunk you want to send to the server. Furthermore, you have to maintain state between this transfers manually and there is no assurance that the files will arrive in the order they are sent.

You should use socket programming with TCP sockets which maintain a connection until the whole file is send. You can then push chunks into the socket and they will arrive without loss and in the same order they are fed to the socket.